# Strange error and Viewing upgrade history of Epson Printer

Tags: printer, firmware, epson-workforce

I have been getting an error on my Epson WF-3640 printer's screen (0x97), and I wanted to try installing the firmware from the website. But when I load the installer, I get the message `Downgraded (It cannot be updated)`.

I do not know what this message means, so I wanted to check to make sure the firmware from the website is indeed newer, but I cannot find a way to view when the currently installed firmware was released/installed, but I can view the last firmware model, and googling that gives me no valid results.

So my two questions would be:

1. What is the 0x97 error.
2. how can I find out when I installed the firmware last/When the firmware I last installed was released?

I have tried Googling around, and I can find nothing for 2, but I have found plenty of people having issues with 0x97.

Comment: More information please. Printer model? Is the error on the printer or on the PC? Upgrading firmware does not fix printer errors. A configuration page (if your printer model does that) should show f/w level. Try the suggestion from wicaksono at http://www.fixya.com/support/t25611196-epson_wf_4630_getting_error_code_0x97

Comment: @hdhondt Sorry, I though I mentioned the model number. I am updating the question

Comment: @hdhondt I looked at wicaksono's answer. I might try that, but I cannot find reference to the code, confirming that is the meaning of the message, so I will leave this open.

Comment: Have you tried the head cleaning as suggested in the link? If that does not work, it looks like a hardware error. If it's under warranty, get a replacement; if not, buy a new printer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I called Epson about 0x97 and was told it means the printer is dead--you can't fix it yourself. You can swap it out if it's still on warranty.

Comment: I ended up doing that. Costco let me exchange it 6 months after Epson warranty expired.